# Minimalist Sphere Impostor -- computing sphere radius in zdepth

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, zbuffer

I'm trying to code up a fast and minimalist sphere impostor-- the sphere doesn't need to be shaded or do anything but correct gl_FragDepth.

I have some code that's very close to working... cutting out everything but the key code:

vertex shader:

```
out_XYZ=float4(sphereCenter.xyz,1.)*sceneComboMatrix;
switch(gl_VertexID)
{
case 0:
    out_XYZ.xy+=vec2(radius,-radius);
    out_UV=float2(1.,-1.);
    break;
case 1:
    out_XYZ.xy+=vec2(-radius,-radius);
    out_UV=float2(-1.,-1.);
    break;
case 2:
    out_XYZ.xy+=vec2(radius,radius);
    out_UV=float2(1.,1.);
    break;
case 3:
    out_XYZ.xy+=vec2(-radius,radius);
    out_UV=float2(-1.,1.);
    break;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
float aLen2=dot(in_UV,in_UV);
float aL=inversesqrt(aLen2);
if (aL<1.) discard;
out_Color=float4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
float magicNumber=.0031f;
gl_FragDepth=gl_FragCoord.z-(sin(1.-(1./aL))*(3.14/2.)*magicNumber);
```

This produces the following:
[image]

Not TOO bad... it works as a proof of concept.  The issue is, my variable magicNumber above, which I simply fiddled around with, should be replaced with the radius of the sphere in zdepth.

How can I compute the size of the sphere's radius in terms of zdepth?

(A note: I don't need this to be hyperaccurate-- it's being used for some particles that can clip slightly wrong... but it does need to be more accurate than my screenshot above)

(EDIT----------)
Using resources from Nicol Bolas, I wrote some code to attempt to get the difference in zdepth between the sphere's maximally close point ot the camera and the sphere's center.  However, the result pushes the sphere VERY FAR toward the camera.  Why doesn't this code give me the length of the sphere's radius in z-space (i.e. the difference in Z between the sphere's center and another point closer to the camera?)

```
vec4 aSPos=vec4(spherePos.xyz,1.)*sceneComboMatrix;
float aD1=aSPos.z/aSPos.w;
aSPos=vec4(spherePos.xyz+(normalTowardCamera.xyz*sphereRadius),1.)*sceneComboMatrix;
float aD2=aSPos.z/aSPos.w;
radiusLengthInZ=((gl_DepthRange.diff*(aD1-aD2))+gl_DepthRange.near+gl_DepthRange.far)/2.0;
```

Comment: "*How can I compute the size of the sphere's radius in terms of zdepth?*" Why do you need to? Just do your computations in world-space or whatever space you like. If you need a depth value, compute it from the hit location by transforming it into window-space. This transformation has nothing to do with the "radius".

Comment: @NicolBolas The sphere is being rendered as an impostor on a billboarded quad... there's no sphere geometry.  What I expected to do was just ease fragments closer to the center of the quad closer to the camera, nothing very fancy.  Since it's part of a particle system, speed is very essential.  That said, what would "compute it from the hit location by transforming it into window-space" look like as shader code?

Comment: It would look [like this](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut13%20Deceit%20in%20Depth.html).

Comment: @NicolBolas Sadly, that involves doing a ray/sphere collsion to get the number-- a computation I'm hoping to avoid per-pixel.  But I might be able to use this to figure out a "zpos closer to the camera" value in the vertex shader, which at least would only have to happen four times per sphere.

Comment: "*Sadly, that involves doing a ray/sphere collsion to get the number*" That's the only way to make a proper sphere impostor. Otherwise, [you get this problem](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut13%20Correct%20Chicanery.html). If you're fine with having this artifact, you can still compute the whatever-space 3D position and use that to compute the depth.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hi again... would you mind taking a look at my edit?  what I want to try to implement is to do only a SINGLE cast toward the sphere to get the maximum "adjustment" I need to do to z, and then use the curve of the sphere to adjust that.  But the calculation (which I took from the example you sent) moves my fragment's depth basically all the way up the camera.  I'm using "radiusLengthInZ" as my magic number, but it's a huge number.

Comment: "*what I want to try to implement is to do only a SINGLE cast toward the sphere to get the maximum "adjustment" I need to do to z, and then use the curve of the sphere to adjust that.*" Spheres are non-linear; there is no single "adjustment" value you can apply to any 2D projected point to get the depth value. Furthermore, depth *itself* doesn't happen in a non-linear space. So even if you did compute a per-pixel "adjustment" value, it wouldn't be able to apply in a non-linear coordinate system. Just compute the 3D position and transform it into window space.

Comment: @NicolBolas But the equations of how OpenGL computes z-space must exist somewhere, right?  I'm not able to find anything on Google, but surely people sometimes compute non-linear z-positions manually for other purposes?

Comment: "*But the equations of how OpenGL computes z-space must exist somewhere, right?*" It's a non-linear function. By definition, "multiply by this value" isn't going to cut it. I don't know why you're hesitating to just do the math on this.

Comment: As I said, this shader is part of a particle system and it's a matter of one sphere/line intersection per particle vs tens of thousands.  Also, there's no reason this can't work for the precision I need for this-- if I can just somehow "peek" what gl_FragDepth is going to eventually be from within the vertex shader.  This isn't an absurd request-- surely there's some way to figure out what value is eventually going to be written for a specific vertex?

Comment: The foundation of what you're trying to do is predicated on the belief that `actualDepth - (radius * f(UV))` will produce a meaningful depth value if you can produce `actualDepth`. It will not. There is no `f(UV)` which can produce a meaningful value to make this equation work.

Comment: I think the problem is that my question is "how do I compute the same z-value that openGL would compute" but you're answering "what's the pixel-perfect way to do a sphere impostor."  Perfect precision is not what I need here-- if I was rendering a sphere that had to stand up to scrutiny I would go with the link you provided.  But I am trying to produce a kludge that may look a little worse, but will be a lot faster.

Comment: If it's just a kludge, why does the depth matter at all? If the particles are so big that the depth interactions actually matter, then they're also going to be so big that you need to do them more accurately. And if those depth interactions are going to matter, you need them to be reasonably accurate. And you're not going to get that with the function you're trying to establish.

Comment: Both for academic curiosity and to see if I can find a happy medium between "looks okay" and "is fast."  People still experiment, right?